# I'm trying to stack some images together but I lost the background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack some images together but I lost the background. I use "position:absolute", the images are stacking very well because the sizes are correct but something happening with both backgrounds (i want to put 3 eggs in a row, that's why I have the .egg-container inside .container).

images:
[top-egg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png)
[bottom-egg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png)

```css
        .container{
            max-width: 50%;
            height: auto;
            background-color: blue;
            margin: 100px auto;
        }

        .container-egg{
            width:21%;
         height:auto;
         margin: 30px auto;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
        }

        .bottom{
            z-index:2;
        }

        .top{
            z-index:3;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            margin-top: -0px; 
            transition: margin-top .2s;
        }
        
        .container-egg:hover > .top{
            margin-top: -100px;
            transform: translate(10px, 0) rotate(10deg);
        }

        .position{
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
         <div class="container-egg">
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png" class="bottom position">
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png" class="top position">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both elements are positioned there are removed from the normal flow and they are no more considered to calculate the height of their container so the container is having a height equal to `0`.

To fix this, simply make only one image positioned:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.container-egg {
  width: 21%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
}
.top {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  margin-top: -0px;
  transition: margin-top .2s;
}

.container-egg:hover>.top {
  margin-top: -30px;
  transform: translate(10px, 0) rotate(10deg);
}

.position {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-egg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png" >
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png" class="top position">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve something like below

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqcevw3f/2/)

CSS Code -

```
.container {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

img.top,
img.bottom {
  width: 100%;
}

.container-egg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  z-index: 2;
}

.top {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  margin-top: -0px;
  transition: margin-top .2s;
}

.container-egg:hover>.top {
  margin-top: -100px;
  transform: translate(10px, 0) rotate(10deg);
}

.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

HTML Code -

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-egg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png" class="bottom">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png" class="top position">
  </div>
  <div class="container-egg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png" class="bottom">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png" class="top position">
  </div>
  <div class="container-egg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5Cp.png" class="bottom">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwum.png" class="top position">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's working but is it necessary the "display: block;" on ".container" class?

Comment: You can skip that style after that it also works fine. Also, if my answer helps you, you can upvote it as well mark it accepted.